# Fetch consecutive rows from python data frame and store in list

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to fetch 4 consecutive rows from a data frame and store them in a list. And would like to stop when "i" reaches its value.
Method1

```html
dfList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  
  tempDF = df.iloc[row[i]:row[i+3]].reset_index(drop=True)
  dfList.append(tempDF)
```

error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Method2:

```html
dfList = []
for i in df:
  
  tempDF = df.iloc[row[i]:row[i+3]].reset_index(drop=True)
  dfList.append(tempDF
```

```html
dfList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  
  tempDF = df[(df.loc[(row[i], row[i+3]))]].reset_index(drop=True)
  dfList.append(tempDF)
```

Nothing is working.

original dataframe:

```html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time
from google.colab import files

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# fix_yahoo_finance to fetch detch of GME directly from the yahoo finance website
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()


# input values
symbol = 'GME' # GME ticker symbol
start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2020-12-31'
# Read data from the website
df = yf.download(symbol,start_date,end_date)

# View data related information
print(df.tail())
print(len(df))
print(df.info()) # check for whether any null values
print(df.index)  #type of index


df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.head()


Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2018-01-02  17.959999   18.290001   17.780001   18.260000   15.953856   2832700
1   2018-01-03  18.290001   18.370001   17.920000   18.200001   15.901433   3789200
2   2018-01-04  18.200001   18.379999   17.959999   18.320000   16.006279   2781300
3   2018-01-05  18.379999   18.730000   18.219999   18.680000   16.320812   3019000
4   2018-01-08  18.799999   19.400000   18.799999   19.230000   16.801352   3668400
```

I want output like :
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXVoj.png)

Comment: Could you please paste the original dataframe into your question so that somebody else can grab it and test it out?

Comment: I have pasted the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think you need to pass "index" instead of "row['index']" in your iloc parameters.

```
dfList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # As long as there are 3 more rows to concatenate
    if(index < df.shape[0] - 3):
        tempDF = df.iloc[index:index+4].reset_index(drop=True)
        dfList.append(tempDF)
```